# Ruby - Reference subclass in class method

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

Not sure if this is possible with Ruby, but I am trying to write a class with several methods that will be shared by a number of subclasses.  This superclass will contain both class and instance methods that I want the subclasses to inherit.  Assume that I will never use the superclass directly, I am only using it to abstract out methods that are repeated (thinking DRY).  This involves having constants (API URIs) that will change from subclass to subclass.

Here's an example of what I am trying to do:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :param
  def initialize(param)
    @param = param
  end
  def self.get
    <SubClass>.new(self::MY_CONSTANT)
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  MY_CONSTANT = 'Woot'
end

class Baz < Foo
  MY_CONSTANT = 'Pew Pew'
end
```

The behavior I want is something like this:

```
Bar.get
puts Bar.param # => Woot
Baz.get
puts baz.param # => Pew Pew
```

Is this possible?  Am I approaching this completely the wrong way?

**Update**

Per @Nathan, `self.new` in the `self.get` method did the trick here.

```
[39] pry(main)> test = Bar.get
=> #<Bar:0x000001072ecc20 @param="Woot">
[40] pry(main)> test.param
=> "Woot"
[41] pry(main)> test
=> #<Bar:0x000001072ecc20 @param="Woot">
[42] pry(main)> test.class
=> Bar
[43] pry(main)> test2 = Baz.get
=> #<Baz:0x000001071b5528 @param="Pew Pew">
[44] pry(main)> test2.class
=> Baz
[45] pry(main)> test2.param
=> "Pew Pew"
```

Comment: You may find it helpful to salt your code `puts` statements that give you the value of `self`. For example, `class Klass; def my_method; puts "self in #{__method__} = #{self}"; end; end; Klass.new.my_method #=>  self in my_method = #<Klass:0x007fbd4987fdd0>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `self`.

Inside `Foo.get`, `self` is the class you're calling `get` on, which would be `Bar` and `Baz` when you execute `Bar.get` and `Baz.get`, respectively.

Therefore, where you have `<SubClass>`, just put `self`, and everything will work as you expect.

```
def self.get
  self.new(self::MY_CONSTANT)
end
```

You can also omit `self` because that's what Ruby uses automatically when no explicit object is specified.

```
def self.get
  new(self::MY_CONSTANT)
end
```

Also, in your code where you're testing the values, I *think* what you intend is this:

```
bar = Bar.get
puts bar.param # => Woot
baz = Baz.get
puts baz.param # => Pew Pew
```

Finally as for whether this is the best way, that's opinion-based, but it seems odd to me that you're trying to pass the value into `initialize` when it's already available as a constant.  In other words, if you have a method that needs to use the API URI, just reference the constant directly rather than initializing the instance itself with `@param`.  You can reference the constant inside an instance method like this: `self.class::MY_CONSTANT`

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  For some reason I was thinking that `self` would be a reference to the current instance of `Bar` or `Baz` so it would be trying to call a .new against an existing instance.  Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: Oh!  And as to your last comment, thank you for that suggestion.  In my real code I am using the constant directly in rest-client calls, rather than assigning it to an instance variable.  Seemed like a quick way to show the desired behavior but it was not complete.  Good catch!